# How to get formatted HTML generated by Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony2 to generate forms, or actually Twig, which uses Symfony's functions, so the view looks like this:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

This generates HTML code without any newlines or indentation. This is unreadable when I look into HTML source code.

Is there any way to force Symfony/Twig to format the generated HTML?

Comment: Look at it in firebug or similar developer tool.

Comment: Did you see recipe from [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)?

Comment: @malcom, thanks, yes, I know that, but you do know that Firebug/Chrome shows corrected source code, so if e.g. there is a closing tag missing, you will not notice this using the above tools. But +1 anyway :)

Comment: @Vladimir Kovpak - thanks, that's OK, although I rather hoped for a general solution, not only for forms. See my own answer. But +1 anyway:)

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://brentertainment.com/other/docs/cookbook/form/twig_form_customization.html) explains form customization in twig beautifully. There are numerous ways of applying css styling to form elements. For example, if you have a form with a field **name** you can add a css class to it this way:

```
{# render a widget, but add a "foo" class to it #}
{{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
```

or to the label:

```
{{ form_label(form.name, 'Your Name', {'label_attr': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
```

Then you can use the **css** classes to render form elements as per your design. Hope you get the idea. The [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html) and link provided in the answer are both useful in this regard.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for a nice article (to read for later), but I didn't mean styling or how the page looks rendered, but rather how HTML source code looks like, I think I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Even for the markup, if you render labels, input fields separately in your code with say <br /> tags, you'll get a clean, readable markup.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** the below "solution" [made me a headache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550166/twig-replaces-non-ascii-characters-with-entities) precisely this line:

`$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');`

It converts all non-ascii characters to entities, which is not very smart. Javascript's `confirm` and `alert` functions don't convert it back to UTF-8, they display strings as they are.

---

Thanks everybody, but I think I wasn't clear enough:) I didn't mean formatting by css or generally changing how the rendered page looks like, but rather changing HTML **source** code.

Anyway, with these two articles I finally managed to do what I wanted:

[How do you format DOM structures in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997936/how-do-you-format-dom-structures-in-php)

http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/10/symfony2-create-a-response-filter-and-set-extra-response-headers/

**Step 1.**

So, first the response listener, in (for example) AppBundle/EventListener/ResponseListener.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;

class ResponseListener {

    private $container;

    public function __construct(Container $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    function tidyHtml($html)
    {
        $dom = new \DOMDocument();

        if (libxml_use_internal_errors(true) === true)
        {
            libxml_clear_errors();
        }

        $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
        $html = preg_replace(array('~\R~u', '~>[[:space:]]++<~m'), array("\n", '><'), $html);

        if ((empty($html) !== true) && ($dom->loadHTML($html) === true))
        {
            $dom->formatOutput = true;

            if (($html = $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG)) !== false)
            {
                $regex = array
                (
                    '~' . preg_quote('<![CDATA[', '~') . '~' => '',
                    '~' . preg_quote(']]>', '~') . '~' => '',
                    '~></(?:area|base(?:font)?|br|col|command|embed|frame|hr|img|input|keygen|link|meta|param|source|track|wbr)>~' => ' />',
                );

                return '<!DOCTYPE html>' . "\n" . preg_replace(array_keys($regex), $regex, $html);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }   


    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        //only when format == html and environment == dev
        if ($request->getRequestFormat() == 'html' && $this->container->get('kernel')->getEnvironment() == 'dev') {
            $event->getResponse()->setContent($this->tidyHtml($event->getResponse()->getContent()));
        }

    }

}
```

**Step 2.**

In services.yml:

```
response_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\ResponseListener
    arguments: ['@service_container']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method : onKernelResponse }
```