# Twig replaces non-ascii characters with entities

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.3

Well, that's really strange, Twig (I'm using it with Symfony 3) replaces non - ascii characters (for example "ł") with entities (e.g. `&#322;`), but... only in Javascript sections.

I have no idea why and how to disable it.

Edit: yes, I have UTF-8 everywhere, in Nebeans and in HTML head section.

Edit2: here is my current code:

```
{% autoescape false %}
    <script>
        $(function(){
            alert('ółż');
        })
    </script>
{% endautoescape %}
```

Even with `{% autoescape false %}` (as suggested by Martin) it still does it.

Comment: Isn't it related to your webpage charset?

Comment: @bart-bartoman I don't thinks so, its `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`, plus it only happens in Javascript tag o_O

Answer (score 3):

Hi if the caracters are in a variable it's normal, to disabled you can use :

```
{{myvar | raw}}
```

Source if you need : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html

Comment: Thanks, but no, it's not a variable, I added a piece of code to my question.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and help, but it appeared that this is because of my stupidity :( I someday wanted a better formatted html code (more readable), so I did this: stackoverflow.com/questions/35064349/… and there is this piece of code: $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'); that was it. Sorry I wasted your time.

Comment: no problem. some problem are simple when you see what is the real problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Twig uses different autoescaping strategies based on the context. See manual http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html

You can force Twig to disable escaping with:

```
{% autoescape false %}
    Everything will be outputted as is in this block
{% endautoescape %}
```

Or for a single print expression with [`raw` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html):

```
{{ var|raw }}
```

Also have a look at your [Twig 's configuration](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#environment-options) where `autoescaping` should be enabled by default.

Edit:

Maybe try also this:

```
<script>
    {% autoescape false %}
        $(function(){
            alert('ółż');
        })
    {% endautoescape %}
</script>
```

Comment: plus, in the first link you gave me, it states "Twig does not escape static expressions:"  like  `set hello = "<strong>Hello</strong>"` then why does it convert my string?

Comment: You're not using static expressions. In your case static expression could be eg. `{{ "alert('ółż');" }}`. When you print `{{ var }}` then it uses escaping as described in the manual.

Comment: but I'm not using variables... I simply do this: `alert('ółż');`

Comment: using this: `alert(' {{ 'ółż' | raw }}');` (raw filter added) also does not work

Comment: The theory that it is caused by Twig is only my theory, maybe there is something else in Symfony what can cause this?

Comment: Maybe try to put the escape block inside `<script>`.  
Have you tried any of these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313255/twig-utf8-character-encoding-symfony2

Comment: thank you very much for your time and help, but it appeared that this is because of my stupidity :( I someday wanted a better formatted html code (more readable), so I did this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064349/how-to-get-formatted-html-generated-by-symfony/35080486#35080486 and there is this piece of code: `$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');` that was it. Sorry I wasted your time.