# How to debug Twig code? Where is its main function?

Tags: symfony, debugging, twig, symfony-2.3

This is related to this: [twig replaces non ascii characters with entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550166/twig-replaces-non-ascii-characters-with-entities)

None of the comments/answers have helped me. I also tried on #Symfony IRC without success.

So I believe my only option is to debug Twig, that is with XDebug and Netbeans I want to use the "Debug project" / "Step into" etc. commands.

But I have no idea where to put my first breakpoint, I can't find where all of this starts in Twig, what's the "main" function.

Comment: Twig gets called when your controller generates the response. Search for the methods "render", "renderView" and "stream" in your controllers.

Comment: I didn't think about it:) Thank you. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig gets called when your controller generates the response. Search for the methods "render", "renderView" and "stream" in your controllers.