# Remove white spaces between tags in HTML

Tags: php, html, regex, domdocument

I am using the following code to remove white spaces in html. I only want to remove white spaces in betweens tags. But below code replaces all white spaces

I.E remove all white spaces in between ">" and "<"

```
//read the entire string
$str=file_get_contents('sample.txt');

//replace all white spaces
$str=str_replace("\n", "",$str);
$str=str_replace("\t", "",$str);
$str=str_replace(" ", "",$str);

//write the entire string
file_put_contents('sample.txt', $str);
```

Comment: You could use `DomDocument` with [`preserveWhiteSpace = false`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace) Additionally a question [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997936/how-do-you-format-dom-structures-in-php).

Comment: you could also use tidy

Comment: Since you don't state your purpose — _why_ you want to remove the whitespace, and at what stage — it's hard to recommend something specific... though [regex is not a good approach](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/17300). I've used tidy/jTiey as Daniel mentions.

Comment: If you really want to use your code, you could try including the closing and opening angle brackets in your matches:  `str_replace(">\n<","><",$str)`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need use a regular expresion.

Maybe you can use this:

```
$html = preg_replace('/\>\s+\</m', '><', $html);
```

Test here [https://repl.it/](https://repl.it/@maflorezp/HTML-Clear-Tags)

Comment: Another simplified version could be `$html = preg_replace( '/>(\s)+</m', '><', $html );`