# How to remove whitespace between html tags with PHP?

Tags: php, html, whitespace

I want to remove whitespaces between html tags.
Example:

```html
<div>
    <div>Hi!</div>
    <div>Bye</div>
</div>
```

I would like to print at the browser this:

```
Hi! Bye
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? To obfuscate your HTML code? With which language are you trying to do that?

Comment: Yea, a little to obfuscate but more important I think it can make it better to browsers read my codes (even if it's 0.04s). And also my emails. I would like to remove this whitespaces. Maybe some bug could happen

Comment: You can refer to this topic if you are using PHP:
[Remove white spaces between tags in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096319/remove-white-spaces-between-tags-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

To print the text in the browser with no spaces you can use `<span>` instead of `<div>`
**You have written your code** like this:

```html
<div>
     <div>Hi!</div>
     <div>Bye</div>
</div>
```

**The output** will be like:

```
Hi!
Bye
```

You are asking it to be like:

```
Hi! Bye
```

**You have to use this code to have the output in the same line:**

```html
<div>
   <span>Hi!</span>
   <span>Bye</span>
</div>
```

And now the **output** will be like:

```
Hi! Bye
```